# Is it necessary to assign "resources" to set in RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I was confused when I read the source code in RxJava:
Is it necessary to assign "resources" to set ?

in class CompositeDisposable
code in Rxjava:

```
 @Override
    public boolean add(Disposable d) {
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(d, "d is null");
        if (!disposed) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (!disposed) {
                    **OpenHashSet<Disposable> set = resources;**
                    if (set == null) {
                        set = new OpenHashSet<Disposable>();
                        resources = set;
                    }
                    set.add(d);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        d.dispose();
        return false;
    }
```

code I've modified:

```
@Override
    public boolean add(Disposable d) {
        ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(d, "d is null");
        if (!disposed) {
            synchronized (this) {
                if (!disposed) {
                    OpenHashSet<Disposable> set = resources;
                    if (resources == null) {
                        resources = new OpenHashSet<Disposable>();

                    }
                    resources.add(d);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        d.dispose();
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please ask your question in the GitHub-Repository: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Comment: `resources` might or might not be null.

Answer (score 0):

It avoids re-reading the instance field. The compiler/JIT may or may not optimize the style you suggested in time or at all - we don't usually take such chances. In addition, the pattern may appear with a `volatile` field that could be expensive to re-read and also may yield different values each time, invalidating the intent of the code.

(Also please don't open an issue/PR attempting to change this pattern as it will be rejected.)